# Allow-Control-Access-Origin header "*" vs origin

Tags: html, http, request, cors, response

I am trying to create white list on the server and set Allow-Control-Access-Origin header if the requested host is within the white list. I have seen all the people saying we should add `Allow-Control-Access-Origin: <request host origin>` in the response header, and I also believe this is the correct way to do this, but I have a question:

If after I find the request comes from a trusted host and add 
`Allow-Control-Access-Origin: *` in the header, will that work as well?

Would the browser remember the * and allow all the future request comes from somewhere to call this server as well? Or if browser will still check this header for every single request. If browser check every request, then what is the different to return * or the specific host origin at this point? Thank you.